# ErrorException (E_ERROR) Undefined variable: empname

Tags: laravel-5

i am having issue undefined variable

this is my controller 
'''

```
if (empty($input['emp_id'])) {
            $empname = $input['emp_first_name'] . " " . $input['emp_last_name'];
            return redirect()->action('EmployeeController@printQr', ['emp_code' => $input['emp_code'], 'empname' => $empname['empname']]);
        } else {
            return redirect()->route('employeeList');
        }
```

'''

this is my print page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<br/><br/>
<img src="{{ Storage::url("emp_qr_codes/") }}{{ $emp_code }}.png" style="width: 250px;"/>
<br/>
Employee Code: {{ $emp_code }}
<br/>
Employee Name: {{ $empname }}
<script>
    var emp_code = @json($emp_code);
    var empname = @json($empname);
    var ttt = '<br><br>' +
        '<img src="{{ Storage::url("emp_qr_codes/") }}' + emp_code + '.png" style="width:250px;" />' +
        '<br>Employee Code: ' + emp_code +
        '<br>Employee Name: ' + empname;
    var newWin = window.open('', 'Print-Window');
    newWin.document.open();
    newWin.document.write('<html><body>' + ttt + '</body></html>');
    newWin.document.close();
    newWin.focus();
    setTimeout(function () {
        newWin.print();
        newWin.close();
    }, 150);
    setTimeout(function () {
        window.location.href = '/employee/index';
    }, 160);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the error I get:
' ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Undefined variable: empname (View: /var/www/html/attendance_system/resources/views/employee/print.blade.php)
Previous exceptions

```
Undefined variable: empname (0)
```

'

Comment: Your controller code of method: EmployeeController@printQr is missing in your code sample. This is where it goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The controller code you show does not render any views.

Controller should have code like this:

```
return view('viewNamw', ['empname' => 'test' ]);
```

This renders a view with variable 'empname' that you can use in blade.

Comment: Can you add explanation for your answer?

Comment: @RubanS your redirect forces you to another URL and thus another controller action. This action probably doesn't provide this variable name to the blade view.